# working with resources that are both nested/non-nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have the following models/relationships in my Rails app:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

and I want reviews to be both a standalone resource and a nested resource of Books:

```
resources :books do
  resources :reviews
end

resources :reviews
```

For example, I want "/reviews" to display the most recent reviews (over all books), and "/book/1/reviews" to display the most recent reviews of book 1.

What's the best way to handle this in my controller and views? For example, do I have a single index action and a single index view, and use some conditional statements to check whether I want to display all reviews or only reviews for a particular book? Or do I have separate all_index and particular_book_index actions and views?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter In ActionController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671620/how-to-filter-in-actioncontroller)

Comment: Please see my answer on the question in the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).